# upgrading font-awesome 4.7 to 6.2 angular 8 project

Tags: angular, font-awesome, package.json, font-awesome-4

In my angular 8 application, where in the parent module uses font-awesome 4.7 as below in package.json;

```
 "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
```

angular.json;

```
"styles": ["projects/adminUI/src/styles.css",
          "./node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"],
```

Now my child module which is developed newly needs to have font-awesome icons of the 6.2.0 version, if I upgrade this to the new version, will there be any impact on existing icons in the parent application? Can anyone suggest if someone has done it before, any pointer would be highly appreciated?

also I have checked 4.7.0 package name different and 6.2.0 package name different so what i do ??

Answer (score 0):

Sadly,I think the answer is No.

When working with Angular source code you are tightly coupled to a specific version of Angular. So most projects on GitHub maintain separate working branches in Git for each Angular version.

You have to then install Angular's compiling chain via **NPM** in the local node_modules and perform builds via **npm build** so that the correct versions of Angular are used to compile that code, because your global install of Angular CLI will likely be tracking the latest stable release